# How to submit Json object that also contains an array?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my jquery function. I'd like to to post this object to the controller. Every thing works fine except the **ListOfCBToDisplay**, which is a list.

```
<script>
function Submit_Movie() {
    //
    var title = $('[id*="Title"]').val();
    var yearOfMaking = $('[id*="YearOfMaking"]').val();
    var description = $('[id*="Description"]').val();

    var movie =
    {
        "Title": title,
        "YearOfMaking": yearOfMaking,
        "Description": description,

        "ListOfCBToDisplay" : []
    };

    //
    var $cbx = $('[id*="cbx"]');        
    $cbx.each(function () {
        var id = GetID($(this).attr('id'));
        var ck = $(this).prop("checked");
        alert(id + ", " + ck);       //The alert is displaying correctly all the values

        var new_obj = { "ID": id, "Value": ck, "Text": "" };
        movie.ListOfCBToDisplay.push(new_obj);
    })

    //
    var url = "@Url.Action("AddEditMovie", "Admin")";
    $.post(url, movie, function (data) {
        location.reload();
    });
}
function GetID(elt_id) {
    var _id = elt_id.split('_');
    if (_id.length == 2) {
        return _id[1];
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is the Movie class

```
public class Movie
{
    public Movie()
    {
        ListOfCBToDisplay = new List<CheckBoxToDisplay>();
    }

    // more properties ...

    public List<CheckBoxToDisplay> ListOfCBToDisplay { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddEditMovie(Movie movie)
    {
        //More here ...
    }
```

Any reason why all the primitive properties are getting their values while the objects in the list have null values, i.e. ID = 0, Text = null, and Value = false ? However, the number of objects is always correct, only the values are null.

Thanks for helping

Comment: 0, null, and false are all 0 internally. Are you sure they are actually getting set?

Comment: I don't know. All the primitives properties, such as Title, Description are getting set correctly. Only the value in the array are not being set. Look at the code. I've put an alert there and I'm getting the correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use JSON to `JSON.stringify(myObject);` the object. Or you can simply serialize your string with the JS `join` method:

```
var myList = [];
$cbx.each(function () {
    var id = GetID($(this).attr('id'));
    var ck = $(this).prop("checked");
    alert(id + ", " + ck);       //The alert is displaying correctly all the values

    var new_obj = id+"~"+ck; // here `~` is id/value separator
    myList.push(new_obj);
})
movie.ListOfCBToDisplay = myList.join("^"); // here '^' is a separator
```

Then in your server side just split the string by using the `^` separator to get list of id/values, then split each of them by `~`. This is basically serializing manually the object.

**EDIT**

Another approach would be to copy all the needed values as `<input type='hidden'>`to an hidden `<form>` then use the JQuery [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) on the form. Maybe you can use the current form to do so.

Comment: When I use JSON.stringify(myObject) or myList.join("^"), the ListOfCBToDisplay is not even being populated. When I go back to my code, ListOfCBToDisplay is a list of the exact number of object. But those objects have only the default, not the incoming values.

Comment: I edited the sample code (I initially overlooked the data format). I also add another approach.

Comment: Thank you for those different possibilities. Actually, I've using the technique where you concatenate values into one string. That way I don't need to create form all over the place. However, you didn't mention that the receiving property in the action should be a string. Thank so much.